# How to remove any permission from app-content in playstore?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

My app was rejected by the Play Store due to some permission violations. Now I have removed all those permissions from the app and want to publish it again. But those permissions exist in app-content as you can see in the below image. and I want to delete them but am unable to find any method to delete them. Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think there isn't a direct way to delete it. The only way I know to change/remove the collected data types is to resubmit the App Content form by clicking on manage in one of the declarations visible in the screenshot. When doing that, you can easily deselect the data types you want to remove.

Hope that helps.

Comment: when I click on manage and try to deselect the options then 'save' button is always disabled and the 'discard changes' button is enabled.

Comment: Is there any 'data type' that isn't filled in?

Comment: All required options are filed.